# Binary to decimal by recursive function

Tags: python

I was trying to make a recursive function that takes
an integer x and returns its binary value i.e takes in 7 and returns 111 but the function i made returns [1,1,1] any ideas ?
Ps no using built in functions!

Comment: how does your attempt look like? Please post your code :)

Comment: Returning `[1,1,1]` sounds good, not you just need to `join` them to a `str` (hint hint). (BTW, make sure the digits are in the right order, which can not easily be inferred from this example, maybe try with another one?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
toBinary = [1,1,1]
return (''.join(str(char) for char in toBinary))
```

This assumes that your function correctly converts from decimal to binary and the only problem is converting list to string.

Comment: Personally, I would not convert the result to `int`. `111` is `111`, not `7`; whereas `"111"` is a (binary) _representation_ of `7`.

Comment: @tobias_k That makes sense, just edited the comment.